# android, Is it possible to load pictures of application from different folders (because of different size of screens)?

Tags: android, image, size

As you now android phones have different sizes. Now, I want to overcome to this limitation with creating different size of pictures and putting them into separate folders. Then say to android that load picture from one of these folders depends of its screen size.

Is this a good way, although other pictures which are stored in other folders will waste memory?

I know we can use drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi but what will happen to tablets? Do they use drawable-hdpi? I'm asking this because I want to know if 4" screen devices (such as Galaxy S) uses drawable-hdpi and bigger screen devices (such as Galaxy tab and Xoom) are using this as well, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. All of your corresponding images must have the same names in each folder, but you generally use the drawable folders inside your applications res folder.
Namely 
drawable-hdpi for high res 
drawable-ldpi for low res and
drawable-mdpi for medium res

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: It really matters what pixel density the screen is using, but they have also added xhdpi for Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Answer (score 0):

You can find all your answers here.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)